# fontFamily "Courier" is not a system font native-base expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, native-base

I'm using native base template for expo `expo-template-native-base`, when launching the iOS simulator I get an error

```
fontFamily "Courier" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:27:16 in processFontFamily
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/renderApplication.js:54:4 in renderApplication
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:213:4 in runApplication
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have to load the font `Courier`.  Download the font from this [director](https://directory.vercel.app/). I've posted an answer on how to load Custom fonts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213782/13170636)

Comment: the Courier font was removed by Apple in iOS 15. only Courier New ships with iOS 15

Comment: Will try, my simulation is running at iPhone 13

Comment: I fixed the issue by replacing Courier with Courier New.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. If anybody resolved this issue, please guide how?

Answer (score 0):

This warning shows that the Courier font you're trying to use in your Expo project isn't available on the device, and you haven't included it as a custom font using `expo-font`. If you have this issue, you can fix it in the following way:

1. Install `expo-font`:`npx expo install expo-font`
2. Download the font: You can download the Courier font from Google Fonts. I have downloaded it from [fonts-free](https://fontsfree.net/courier-font-download.html).
3. Add the font to your Expo project, and create a fonts folder. Usually in the project root or assets folder.
4. Import and load the font:

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { useEffect } from "react";

const loadFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
   Courier: require('./fonts/Courier.ttf'), // Replace with path
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  loadFonts();
}, []);
```

5. Use the font in your styles, once the font is loaded, you can reference it using its name ('Courier')